# How can I force a matrix with variables to be interpreted as singular?

Tags: matrix

I have a matrix `M = {{0,1,b},{a,0,1},{1,c,0}}`.

For my work, I need to assume that $M$ is singular, i.e. $abc+1=0$. The issue is that I am trying to work out `NullSpace[M]`, it assumes that the determinant is nonzero. I have tried using `Refine`, but it seems to make no difference, even if I add `Assumptions -> {a==1,b==-1,c==1}`. Any ideas on how I can make Mathematica interpret the matrix as singular?

Comment: Can you just replace `c` with `-1/(a b)`?

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. I guess I kept thinking that I'd see $a,b,c$ in the final expression that I didn't even think of replacing them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create an explicit matrix-times-vector equation, with extra conditions that the vector not vanish and the determinant vanish.

```
mat = {{0, 1, b}, {a, 0, 1}, {1, c, 0}};
vec = Array[x, Length[mat]];
Solve[Flatten[{Det[mat], mat . vec, vec[[1]] - 1}] == 0, vec, 
 MaxExtraConditions -> Infinity]

(* Out[183]= {{x[1] -> ConditionalExpression[1, 1 + a b c == 0], 
  x[2] -> ConditionalExpression[a b, 1 + a b c == 0], 
  x[3] -> ConditionalExpression[-a, 1 + a b c == 0]}} *)
```

Here I forced the first vector component to be 1. In cases where it has to vanish this won't work, but one could do similar but setting a random linear combination of the vector components to 1.